# Create pdf using rotativa and save to Azure blob

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure-blob-storage, rotativa

I am trying to create a pdf of my View in my MVC project and save it to an Azure blob storage without having a copy of the file on my server.

I am using Rotativa to create my pdf and this works fine.

```
return new ActionAsPdf(ContractVersion) { FileName = "documentname.pdf" };
```

I use the following code to save a file to Azure Storage.

```
  CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

        // Retrieve a reference to a container.
        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("contracts");

        // Retrieve reference to a blob named "myblob".
        CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("myblob");

        // Create or overwrite the "myblob" blob with contents from a local file.
        using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(@"c:\test blob.txt"))
        {
            blockBlob.UploadFromStream(fileStream);
        }
```

But I don't know how to bring the two functions together to create the pdf from view then save to blob.

I hope that my problem is clear. Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 1):

I achieved it using an MVC5 Partial View in a controller method, I have abbreviated it for clarity and not shown my Azure service object that returns the blob object as this is standard MS stuff. Works like a treat!

1. Return pdf from Rotativa;
2. Use "BuildPdf" to convert to byte array;
3. Put it in a memory stream;
4. Upload to Azure Blob using UploadFromStream on Blob object

   `var file = new Rotativa.PartialViewAsPdf("viewname", model) { FileName = "test" + ".pdf" };
   byte[] applicationPDFData = file.BuildPdf(this.ControllerContext); 
   Stream stream = new MemoryStream(applicationPDFData); 
   blob.UploadFromStream(stream);`

Answer (score 0):

I have download the assembly. It only has three construct function. All functions will create pdf file.

[image]

It seems that we need to save the pdf as template file, then upload to Azure Blob.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I suppose that I have a few options? I could create a file on my server, upload it to blob then delete it again. Or perhaps, I could try to look for an alternative pdfwriter. What is the recommended approach? I'm a novice in this area and have never really saved server files, so I don't want to proceed down the wrong path. Thanks again.